# can we use table based navigation in single view application?

Tags: ios

I have created single view iOS application with some basic functionality. and added the table view in simple view controller now I wanted to use table view with row navigation like(pushcontroller and popcontroller) is that possible and if it is, how we can set that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need full support for push/pop operation, I would use a navigation controller.

On the other hand, you could simply present your detail view controllers when a table row is tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MyViewController* detailController = <CREATE THE VIEW CONTROLLER>;
  [self presentViewController:detailController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

In this case, your `detailController` will need to implement a sort of navigation bar or other mechanism to let the user dismiss the controller (through `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`) and go back to the table view. (Using a navigation controller would instead take care of this in a canonical way.)

One major drawback of the simpler solution based on presenting/dismissing is the fact that all the view controllers presented this way are dismissed at once, so you cannot have multiple levels of navigation.

EDIT:

To add a navigation controller to your app, simply do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...
  MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

  ...

  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

  ...

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

At the moment, your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method should use the `addSubview` method to make your main view controller (named `MyViewController` in my example) visible. You can replace that call by the code above to instantiate the navigation controller and push on to it your main view controller.

Alternatively, you could create a new Xcode project using the navigation-based template and move all of your source files over.

Comment: how is it possible to use navigation controller in single view application..?

Comment: Thanks @sergio it works. but one thing i didn't understand while using this method [self.navigationController pushViewController]
where does that navigationController instance is comming from on self

Comment: you are welcome; as to `navigationController`, it is a property of `UIViewController`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926